# Help required to install Oracle JDK 8 on Ubuntu 15.10 - Where and how?

Tags: java, jdk

edit - the above link answered my question - it's up and running!.  thanks Pilot6 and shadow.

I am a Linux newbie.  I am trying to install the Oracle JDK 8 and NetBeans on my computer.

My internet connection is quite slow, so I have previously downloaded the tar.gz file from Oracle.  However, being such a newbie, I'm already stuck.

The instructions tell me to locate it in a folder of my choice, then extract and install it by running tar.
Is there a preferred location?
I attempted to create a /usr/java folder via the graphical interface, but I seem to require root access, and don't quite know hope that works.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Comment: Is it 8 or 9???

Comment: @Pilot6 - It's JDK 8 - i corrected the error.
I'll also check the link you provided.  Thank you.

Comment: I wrote the answer. You can install 8 or 9 this way.

Comment: Due to my slow Internet, I need to avoid automatic updates.  I'm a newbie, will that go out and try and download the JDK?  I downloaded it the last time I had access to fast internet, and so already have the tar.gz file.  Is Java 9 already out?  It was only a few weeks ago when I got jdk8_74.

Comment: @itDontMeanAThing it will only update IF you explicitly permit. Like with that Ubuntu Software Center updates (it will ask) or with APT via `sudo apt-get update` in terminal (you commanded it). SO no problems. 

That being said, I think it is duplicated question. I flagged it.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your downloaded file into

```
/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/
```

Please make sure you have the correct file, at the moment of writing this would be *jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz*

The *oracle-java8-installer* should then recognize the file and not attempt to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This is the easiest way to install it. And you will get automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in terminal:

First you have to add oracle's repository where you can download java

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

And the you must update your local package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can download the installer

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: As mentioned, due to very slow internet, I can't download it, I am trying to install a previously downloaded tar.gz file.  I think the link to the previously answered question is going to be very helpful.  Thanks.